# Delete folder using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, filesystems

I am trying to delete 3 folders using AS3, the folders I am trying to delete are a few directories up from my application storage directory, basically I am trying to delete

```
/data/data/air.<appID>/cache/.AIR 
/data/data/air.<appID>/cache/webviewCache 
/data/data/air.<appID>/databases
```

here is the code I have thus far, but it does not seem to work,

```
var directory:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("../../cache/.AIR");
var directory1:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("../../cache/webviewCache");
var directory2:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("../../databases");

directory.deleteDirectory(true);
directory1.deleteDirectory(true);
directory2.deleteDirectory(true);
```

any ideas as to why? Basically I am just trying to clear my applications webview cache.

Comment: Did you check to make sure directory, directory1, directory2 aren't null? Also, the "../../" might not be needed.

Comment: I did check yes, using `directory.exists`, which returned true. Oh ok, how would I reference the directories then?

Comment: Try this: var directory:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("cache/.AIR");

Comment: That does not seem to work, when I get the nativepath, I get `/data/data/air.<appID>/cache/.AIR/cache/.AIR`, and when I check if the directory exists, I get false.

Comment: Are you sure that directories are non-empty? When you set the deleteDirectoty parameter to true, the call to the method deletes non-empty directories; otherwise, only empty directories are deleted.

Comment: Is there a way to delete a folder regardless of of it is empty or not? Or will that happen if I set it to false?

Comment: It will delete the folder if it's empty, if you remove "true".

Comment: Use directory.getDirectoryListing().count == 0 to check for empty

Comment: `getDirectoryListing()` returns an array, so you would have to write `directory.getDirectoryListing().length`

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be throwing exception since you are trying to delete file/s which are being used/open.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete tee application specific directories that are not empty.  This is widely known issue with Air Apps.You can see a lot of complaints about it on Adobe forums. You can try writing a win32  extension which you add to your app.In windows API you can detect tee leftovers of your app by scanning  the registry and remove the junk. But I am not sure your users will be happy to have such a thing running on their machine  ;)